# проверка на существование файла си

Tags: c++, c, ооп, исключения

Как проверить на существование файла си?

```
try {
    if ((fopen_s(&f, filename, "r") != NULL) {     //так не получается
        cout << "File is open" << endl;
        fclose(f);
    }
    else
        throw (FileOpenError(filename, "file wasn't open!"));   
}
catch (FileOpenError& ex) {
    cout << ex.what();
}
```

Comment: А функцию `stat` религия использовать позволяет?...

Comment: Атомарно или нет? Если атомарно, то надо открывать, если нет, то можно и `stat()`.

Comment: @Harry, `stat()` не атомарен.

Comment: все, проблему решил)) с помощью errno_t

Comment: А каким образом рядом оказались теги `c`, `ооп` и `исключения`?

Comment: @PinkTux работа с файлом методами си

Comment: В C уже появлиись ооп и исключения? И какое оти имеют отношение к "работа с файлом методами си"?

Comment: @PinkTux говорю же " работа с файлом методами си")) просто если с++ то было бы куча вариантов с fstream

Comment: Так Вы и пишите код на Си. Показываете код на плюсах, и говорите про какие-то методы Си. Методы Си - это что ? Обработать исключение ? Манера писать ```if( ( var = function() )  != com_var )``` ? Или что-то другое ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решена с помощью errno_t

```
errno_t err;

FILE *f;
char* filename = "my.txt";
try {
    err = fopen_s(&f, filename, "r");
    if(err == 0){
        cout << "File is open" << endl;
        fclose(f);
    }
    else
        throw (FileOpenError(filename, "file wasn't open!"));   
}
catch (FileOpenError& ex) {
    cout << ex.what();
}
```